# How to add CDNUM in abcde multi-disk alboms in OUTPUTFORMAT

Tags: cd-ripping, abcde

When ripping multi-disk alboms I'd like to have CD number (specified by -w or -W) to be specified in OUTPUTFORMAT. The abcde.conf comments refer to TRACKNUM only, no CDNUM.
Currently both options (w,W) have bugs:

**-w n** produces file: `artist-albom-01.mp3` and overwrites it at next cd rip.

**-W 1** produces file: `artist-albom-101.mp3` but incorrectly labels mp3 tag track 101 of 22

Idealy I'd like to use **-w 1** with CDNUM in OUTPUTFORMAT to get: `artist-albom-1-01.mp3` with mp3 tags: track= 01 of 22, comment=CD1.
Any advice on how to specify CD num in output file name?

Answer (score 0):

By looking into abcde script I noticed **-W** option sets `DISCNUMBER` variable and **-w** option does not. Looks like a bug to me. Below is my patch which allowes you to specify CD number by `DISCNUMBER` variable:
`OUTPUTFORMAT='${ARTISTFILE}-${ALBUMFILE}-${DISCNUMBER}-${TRACKNUM}'`

abcde_disknum.patch

```
--- /usr/bin/abcde.v2.7.1   2015-11-02 18:11:01.000000000 -0500
+++ /usr/bin/abcde  2021-02-04 22:05:14.449596473 -0500
@@ -3815,7 +3815,10 @@
        V) EXTRAVERBOSE=$(($EXTRAVERBOSE + 1)) ;;
        x) EJECTCD="y" ;;
        X) CUE2DISCID="$OPTARG" ;;
-       w) COMMENT="$OPTARG" ;;
+       w) 
+                   DISCNUMBER="${OPTARG}"
+                   COMMENT="CD${OPTARG}"
+                   ;;
        W) if echo $OPTARG | grep "[[:digit:]]" > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
             STARTTRACKNUMBER="${OPTARG}$(printf %02d ${STARTTRACKNUMBER:-01})"
             STARTTRACKNUMBERTAG="y"
```

to apply patch `$ sudo patch /usr/bin/abcde abcde_disknum.patch`